# Compiling gRPC using MSYS2/Mingw32

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, protocol-buffers, grpc

I've come across an issue whilst trying to compile the latest branch of grpc under MSYS2, using mingw64 as suggested by the official installation guide.

The latest gcc for msys2 is 5.2.0, which isn't exactly on good terms with grpc. Still, downgrading to 4.9.1 helped a bit. Through a lot of manual editing of the makefile and a couple C headers, I was finally able to compile all the dependencies. As far as I can tell, most objects had successfully compiled. However, make keeps failing with the error "no target to make libgrp.dll, required by shared_c"(might not be perfect wording). I end up with botched static libs that are recognized by Qt as lacking symbols.

I would greatly appreciate a reliable compilation guide for grpc, and/or precompiled binaries fit for Qt 5.5 32-bit. I know the project is not too mature just yet, but it looks very promising and I can't wait to work with it!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're right that mingw isn't quite a first class citizen for grpc, but it's something we're looking to work on soon. Please file bugs at http://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues for anything you find!

That said, we do test the C codebase against Visual Studio 2013 regularly. I expect C++ to be tested regularly soon, along with VS2015. Could VS2015 be the solution to your problems, given it's now a free download?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, in the end I just switched to VS2013 with the Qt AddIn. 2015 stil isn't supported too well by Qt.

Comment: I am also looking out for creating a  grpc server using MinGW. Any references available now?